# (Viglen / Tesco) Connect 8.9 - simultaneous charge and USB access

Tags: windows-10

I recently bought the Tesco Connect 8.9, I wanted to buy this as a cheap option of running a second (primarily) remote accessible device. The touchscreen is damaged, and isn't worth replacing, which is fine, as I only bought the tablet for a few pounds.

The only problem is, I can only seemingly either charge the device, or use USB (which is going to be a bare minimum requirement).

I have OTG adapters (switched) which work on other tablets (Nexus 7, Ployer Momo 7W etc) which all allow for both USB and OTG, however these devices do not work on this Tesco / Viglen device.

Is there any other way anyone knows about as I thought this was a (primarily) kernel issue on Android, but this device is windows 10. If it isnt a kernel its normally a physical wiring requirement on the OTG device (which as far as I know should be included within the switch element) so I just dont quite understand what is not working?

Any idea's how I can have this working?